# How to reference emails.$.address within afFormGroup using Meteor AutoForm and SimpleSchema?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I've search high and low, and the best I've seen is [this example using afQuickField](https://gist.github.com/openqubit/12ebcce5f91228e2a295b8ff0327512b). I really don't want to create "special" schemas *just* to be able to submit an email while creating a new Meteor user using AutoForm with SimpleSchema.

*What is the exact way* to create a form using AutoForm that I can use to create a new user in Meteor manually by calling `Meteor.createUser()` server-side?

I understand how to use form hooks on submit...how to use afArrayField... but I just want to pass a value for `emails.$.address` from a form using `afFormGroup`... how??

I've tried...

```
{{> afFormGroup name="emails[0].address" type="text" label=false placeholder="schemaLabel" formgroup-class="o-group"}}
{{> afFormGroup name="emails.[].address" type="text" label=false placeholder="schemaLabel" formgroup-class="o-group"}}
{{> afFormGroup name="emails.$.address" type="text" label=false placeholder="schemaLabel" formgroup-class="o-group"}}
{{> afFormGroup name="emails.address" type="text" label=false placeholder="schemaLabel" formgroup-class="o-group"}}
```

...all to no avail. Seems like this is common enough that it should be simple.

```
{{> afFormGroup name="emails" type="text" label=false placeholder="schemaLabel" formgroup-class="o-group"}}
```

When I submit using the pattern in the link and last example above, I get an error that states "emails must be an array".

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to index the first array element in this case is `emails.0.address`. Have a look at the autoform docs: http://autoform.meteorapp.com/update-array-item. Also this thread might be of interest for you: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/200.